# Sonarqube php coverage in interfaces and abstract class

Tags: php, sonarqube, code-coverage, code-analysis

Sonarqute is showing 0% coverage in abstract class and interfaces when phpunit html coverage report show not applicable.

- php 7
- phpunit 6
- SonarQube 6.2 (installed from official apt repositories)
- SonarQube Scanner 2.8
- SonarQube's PHP Plugin 2.9.2.1744 installed

phpunit config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Feature Tests">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Unit Tests">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true" processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
      <log type="coverage-html" target="./testresults/codecoverage" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true" lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80"/>
      <log type="coverage-clover" target="./testresults/test-clover.xml"/>
      <log type="testdox-text" target="./testresults/log.txt"/>
      <log type="junit" target="./testresults/test-unit.xml"/>
    </logging>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Global results by phpunit html report.

[image: global results phpunit]

A result of abstract class coverage by phpunit html report

[image: abstract class phpunit]

Global results by sonar using same test-clover.xml

[image: global results sonar]

A result of abstract class coverage by sonar using same test-clover.xml

[image: abstract class sonar]

Is there some config to adjust sonarqube and get the same % that phpunit analysis html report?

Comment: your pictures are really of poor quality, could you improve it?

Comment: @ElenaVilchik sorry for poor image quality. I already improve.

Comment: SonarPHP 2.10 is released https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarPHP. It fixes ticket jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPHP-680 which might help you.

Comment: Thx. This version fix.